# Inserting values in Hive through select

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to insert certain derived values in hive column and wondering why it's not working. My code is given below.

```
Insert into month as select month(datestamp) as month from gc_1;
```

Here **month** column already exists with NULL values in it and gc_1 is the table name. 
I am not sure whether its possible to add column in hive from another column using functions like **month**, **date** etc.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, here's what I think you are trying to achieve:  There is a table named `gc_1` in which a column already exists called `datestamp` that presumably contains a date string suitable as a parameter for the `month` function.  You would then like to create a new column in `gc_1` named `month` (I don't recommend that, by the way, since `month` is also the name of the built-in function) and populate it with the calendar month of all corresponding values in the `datestamp` column.

Assuming I've interpreted your intention correctly, here is one general way to go about it:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS SELECT *, MONTH(datestamp) AS month FROM gc_1;
```

Once you have verified that the contents of `temp_table` are what you expect, drop `gc_1` and rename `temp_table` to `gc_1`.

```
DROP TABLE gc_1;
ALTER TABLE temp_table RENAME TO gc_1;
```

This of course will temporarily duplicate `gc_1`, so sensible caveats about making sure you have adequate storage apply.

As an alternative, there is a way to avoid storing a duplicate table:

```
ALTER TABLE gc_1 ADD COLUMNS (month INT);
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE gc_1 SELECT column1, column2, ..., MONTH(datestamp) FROM gc_1;
```

This directly overwrites the original table, so a second table is not created.  However, there are some drawbacks with this option:

- Without creating a copy of `gc_1` first, if anything goes awry during the overwrite it cannot be undone.
- You have to enumerate every single column of `gc_1` (and in the correct order) in the query.  If `gc_1` is a wide table with many fields, this can quickly become tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Thanks rchang. And you understood it perfectly. However the table size is huge and dont have an option to create temp_table. So I believe the second pass will work for me. Let me try and let you know .